# Добавление записи в MySQL через html форму

Tags: php

HTML-форма,для добавления записи в MySQL.Нужно чтобы после ввода строки username,была проверка на незанятость данного никнейма,если такого логина нету-добавление записи в бд,а если такой уже существует,чтобы писало,что данный логин уже занят

```
   <?php
   $host="localhost";
$user="root";
$pass=""; //установленный вами пароль
$db_name="pubg";
$link=mysql_connect($host,$user,$pass);
mysql_select_db($db_name,$link);


if (isset($_POST["username"])) {
$login = htmlspecialchars($_GET['username']);
$query = "SELECT * FROM workers WHERE username='$login';"; 
$res=mysql_query ($query);
$alluser = mysql_fetch_array ($res);
if($login == $sql['username']) 
{  
$sql = mysql_query("INSERT INTO `workers` (`username`, `password`)  VALUES 
('".$_POST['username']."','".$_POST['password']."')");
echo "Пользователь добавлен!"; 
} 
else 
{ 
echo "Такой логин уже используется!"; 
} 
} 
?>
```

форма

```
<table>
<form action="" method="post">
    <tr>
        <td>Логин:</td>
        <td><input type="text" name="username"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Пароль:</td>
        <td><input type="text" name="password"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="2"><input type="submit" value="OK"></td>
    </tr>
</form>
</table>
```

Answer (score -1):

```
if (isset($_POST["username"])) {
$login = htmlspecialchars($_GET['username']);
```

Если есть ПОСТ username и дальше пытаетесь GET забрать. Которого как я понимаю нет. Измените $_GET на $_POST как в условии